# How to remove long commands from the bash history

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there an easy way (i.e. bash command) to remove commands that are excessively long from my bash history? Some long commands are basically making <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> unusable. (Ideally I would also not save excessively long commands to the history in the future.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a bash function such as this:

```bash
myhistory(){
   history -w
   gawk -i inplace '{if(length($0)<60)print}' "$HISTFILE"
   history -c
   history -r
}
```

Run it when you want to save the in-memory history to the file,
`history -w`, then use gnu `awk` to edit this file and write back into it
only lines that are shorter than your limit, here 60. Clear the in-memory
history, `-c`, and read it back into memory from the file, `-r`.

If you want to do this with every command you type, you can call it just
before each prompt by setting `PROMPT_COMMAND='myhistory'`.

Comment: +1.  this is the answer I came here to write (you beat me by  7 hours :).   The only thing I have to add is that instead of awk (or in addition to it) you can also edit $HISTFILE with `vi` (or preferred editor) or sed or perl or any other text processing tool.  The key detail in this answer is to write the HISTFILE, modify it using any method, clear the current shell's history, then read in the modified HISTFILE.

Comment: The version of gawk that I have available (GNU Awk 4.0.2) doesn't seem to support the argument -i, I worked around it by creating a temporary file.

Answer (score 3):

You can display the Bash history via the command

```
history
```

From there, you can delete from the history the unwanted command number *n* via the command

```
history -d <n>
```

Note that you can specify (and hence delete) multiple command numbers at once.

---

Also, to avoid that a run command is saved to the history, prepend that command by a space before running it.

```
[root@mylinuxbox ~]# cat /etc/hostname
```

will be saved to the history.

```
[root@mylinuxbox ~]#  cat /etc/hostname
```

will not be.

This behaviour is activated, as pointed out by @phuclv in the comments, by setting the `HISTCONTROL` variable as such (e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`):

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer a method that automatically detects a long line though rather than to have to dig through the history to find these lines.

Comment: you'll need to set [`ignoreboth` or `ignorespace`](https://askubuntu.com/q/15926) in order for that to work

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `~/.bash_history` with an editor and delete the lines.

Comment: Not only this is cumbersome to do, it won't work for the current session, only for already terminated sessions.